# NuVinci continuous shifter

Tags: grip-shifter

I'm building a bike for a woman who injured her hands in a fall and who now experiences pain when using trigger shifters. She does a little better with grip-shifters though even their resistance gives her trouble if she has to shift often. Does a NuVinci hub with its continuous/stepless grip-shifter have a mechanism that is easier to twist than a normal grip-shifter?

BTW, is NuVinci still in the human-powered bicycle business? Some links on their web page go to non-existent pages, and they don't have any dealers in my metro area, which has over 6 million people.

Comment: Is her other hand fine? Wouldn’t it be possible to mount a grip shifter on the other side? What about electronic shifting?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written "hands".  When biking, a rider in front of her suddenly stopped short and she fell forward and broke her fall with her hands.  I wasn't aware of the electronic, thanks.

Comment: Just did a quick check -- the electronic are well beyond budget unfortunately.

Comment: Enviolo/nuvinci isn't all that low-resistance to shift. I wonder if one of the longer sram gripshift models might be a good choice, because they draw more on hand than finger strength. Also maybe a 1x di2 or axs setup, since it saves on a wheel build and if rider doesn't necessarily want a nuvinci type bike. The system is okay for bikes where an igh would be at home anyway, but is pretty clunky otherwise.

Comment: @NathanKnutson  Thanks for the heads up about the resistance, and the sram suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The NuVinci system is quite interesting. There is no spring to pull against in the shifting mechanism, the shifter relies on two gear cables. You could reduce the required effort by using the best quality cables and housings available. There is resistance on the shifter though, not dissimilar to a normal grip shifter but without the clicks to power over. Whether it would suit your application very much depends on whether it's easier by a big enough margin to be noticeable.

NuVinci changed their marketing name to enviolo fairly recently. The products are basically the same though. https://www.enviolo.com/en/

Like you might expect, you'll only know for sure once you've tried it. Does anyone in your area use one of these systems?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It's the *accumulated* effort that causes her pain, and not having to power over the clicks might be enough of a difference.That small difference with each shift might add up to a pain-free ride.  I don't know of anyone with this hub and there are no dealers within a thousand miles of me according to the NuVinci website, FWIW.  We've decided to take a leap of faith and order a relatively inexpensive discontinued model from an online vendor and see what it's like.

Comment: I bought the same, old stock N330. Let me know if you need the instructions. It's a nice hub, very smooth. @Tim

Comment: Thanks for the offer, much appreciated.